# Initialize static property with anonymous method?

Tags: c#, properties, static

I have the following property:

```
protected static string Port { get; } = GetPort();

private static string GetPort()
{
    var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
    tcpListener.Start();
    var port = ((IPEndPoint)tcpListener.LocalEndpoint).Port.ToString();
    tcpListener.Stop();
    return port;
}
```

Can I somehow use something like an anonymous method to just insert the code in `GetPort()` next to the property `protected static string Port { get; } =`?

Comment: Why don't use a static constructor?

Comment: @enkryptor [CA1810](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182275.aspx)

Comment: @enkryptor a static constructor is an option but this is part of a big integration test setup with partial classes and I do have a static construtor with lots of content but if I initialize Port in the static constructor the order becomes important. I'm worrying that the next developer might access port before it has been initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
protected static Func<string> Port { get; } = () =>
    {
        // ...

        return port;
    }
```

And you can modify it, to be called at once on first access, and only once, as suggested by [Dennis_E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594485/dennis-e) in the comments:

```
protected static string Port { get; } = ((Func<string>)(() =>
    {
        // ...

        return port;
    }))();
```

The question is, why should you want that? Your current solution is much better and is compatible with FxCop ([CA1810](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182275.aspx)) so I would leave it as it is.

Another possibility is a simple getter:

```
protected static string Port
{
    get
    {
        // ...

        return port;
    }
}
```

Note that in the first case, the usage is a bit awkward:

```
var p = Port();
```

and in the simple getter case (and your version) it's natural:

```
var p = Port;
```

Comment: The `Func` solution is not the same. The code will execute every time `Port()` is called. `Port { get; } = GetPort();` will only execute it once.

Comment: Yes, as @Dennis_E points out, only one time execution is the important aspect since the same port should be used by several applications (this is used for modifying a number of config files in an integration test with multiple processes).

Comment: @Drutten But as BartoszXP points out, your current solution is much better anyway.

Comment: @Dennis_E I feel that my solution becomes too flexible. Initializing the value directly would signal the staticness of the property. :D

Comment: @Drutten You can make it: `static string Port { get; } = ((Func<string>)(() => { /* do stuff... */ return port;}))();` That's ugly, though.

Comment: @Dennis_E: That's the one! Cool. I'll stick with what I have.

Comment: @Dennis_E I suspected that this was the intent (one evaluation), but couldn't accord it with wanting to have a lambda. Seems it was just curiosity, which is fine :) I've added this to the answer.